# Is the money transfer in Casino Royale a plot hole?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, casino-royale

I am not sure if I am missing something but I feel like there is a plot hole in Casino Royale in regard to the money transfer.

After Mathis is tasered and taken away, Mendel (the banker guy) shows up with the money transfer suitcase where a **bank account number** and **a password** need to be entered. It can be ANY account in the world, as he says before the Poker game:

> The money will remain in escrow until I return... ...and the winner of
>   the contest enters his or her password... ...into the encryptor...
>   ...whereupon the entire sum will be wired... ...to any bank account in
>   the world you nominate.

So Vesper chooses a bank account that was presumably given to her by the bad guys, it is not the actual treasury account. That's all good.

But why would Vesper **personally** need to withdraw the money from the bank in Venice? The bank account is owned by the bad guys, they can withdraw it themselves. Why does she personally need to do it? It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is plothole.

To open a Bank account you would need to provide certain details with which the identity of the person who is opening the account can be determined.

Now imagine if you are a bad guy would you prefer to give out your account number to a government personal, with which you could be traced.  You will also expose all the other accounts with which you might have done transactions, exposing the other parties, and also lose your credibility.

So it would be better to have the money in cash and then deposited into the bank account, with a proper legal explanation in the organization account books.

Vesper was working along with the bad guys because they had kidnapped her boyfriend and holding him.

From Wikipedia

> Bond rejoins MI6 and learns that Vesper had a French-Algerian boyfriend who was kidnapped by the organisation behind Le Chiffre and Mr. White to blackmail her into co-operation

What if,

- Once she finds out that she was used, she goes back and informs the superiors about it.
- Or MI6 could get the information from the bank and proceed on investigation

So, for Mr.White it would be safe if they could get it from her as cash directly instead of giving her an account number to transfer to.  All trails of the money would end with her.

Comment: I thought about this and while it does sound like a valid point I still find it hard to believe that such a sophisticated criminal organization would have any problem at all to siphon the money from a bank account and cover their tracks. But it's still as good as it gets answer so thank you.