# Why did Vesper Lynd carry millions of cash in a gray briefcase? Safer alternative?

Tags: casino-royale

Just edit this if I forgot details. I can't remember how much, but Vesper Lynd withdrew millions of cash from a bank in Venice, put it in this gray briefcase, and walked it to Gettier. Later, when Bond fights Gettier and his henchmen, Gettier loses grip of the briefcase and briefcase falls in water. Later Mr. White retrieves it, but I don't know how. This can be a separate question. The point is, don't store cash in a briefcase!

[Is the money transfer in Casino Royale a plot hole?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33056) explains why Lynd and QUANTUM don't want bank transfers that can be traced. I don't know if any crypto currency was available in 2006, when this movie was released. But why didn't Vesper buy a certified check? What was safer alternative to carrying Millions of cash?

[image]

Comment: Bitcoin was created in 2008. Easy to google, or [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin)

Comment: What makes you think a certified cheque can't be traced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remeber reading some spy memoirs who said that it's psychological effect that money in neat form, like in briefcase (or stacked on the table), look more impressive. Even if they had only $1 bills people would believe there is million in a suitcase while real million in $100 bills in paper bag would not look like one.

He described that during some fairs they tried to buy technology or knowledge and people were baited with a suitcase full of money as 10% of what they will get and that they were really dissapointed when they were paid in gold and jewellery.

So I would say this is a similar move but toward a viewer. It look better than a fanny pack with few golden coins and diamond ring. Not to mention that fighting and loosing such briefcase make for a good cinematic.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a plot hole at all. Maybe a tired trope, sure.

Or if you factor in the *weight* of all that paper money carried one-handed, it can be one. But this is a Bond movie we are talking about.

Besides, it's pretty much a *requirement* for the "ill-fated shady money exchange" trope. Unless some "l33t h@x0r" plot is involved, the bag full of money is the only form of monetary exchange that lends itself to things going wrong.

As a side note, I am not sure how cryptocurrency is even relevant. Unless you specifically want cryptocurrency in your script you can just hand-wave it with some electronic banking magic anyway. Like they do in the exact same movie.

Reference:
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BriefcaseFullOfMoney